# Caffe, how to run classify.py for a set of images

Tags: python, image, caffe

I installed Caffe on Linux successfully. Then I failed to make it work with Matlab. So I installed it with Python following the tutorial of [Pete Warden](http://radar.oreilly.com/2014/07/how-to-build-and-run-your-first-deep-learning-network.html). However, I never used Python before I just run the command `"python python/classify.py --print_results examples/images/cat.jpg foo"` and it works.

My question is how can I test `calssify.py` for a set images rather than a single image? I tried to read images from test directory as following

```
cd caffe
Python
Import os
For file in os.listdir(“example/images”):
     python/classify.py --print_results os.path.join(“examples/images/”,file) foo
```

but it returns each time

> Error; Syntax inccorct

I just work intuitively as in Matlab. Do I need to compile `classify.py` before using it? Is the passage of arguments correct?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, this works for files in a dir

```
mypath = './'
files = [ f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath,f)) ]
for f in files:
    print join(mypath,f)
```

so perhaps you should modify yours to something like

```
import os
from os.path import isfile, join

mypath = './example/images/'
files = [ f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath,f)) ]
for f in files:
    cmd = "python python/classify.py --print_results %s foo" % join(mypath,f)
    os.system(cmd)
```

Comment: Thanks Shawn for your reply, Following your instructions I tried this  `mypath = './examples/images/'
for f in files:
    python/classify.py --print_results os.path.join(mypath,f) foo` but still giving the same error

Comment: so lets simplify the problem. what happens when you comment the for loop, so `# for f in files:` and put in a line above the print that is `f = "cat.jpg"`.

Comment: If I run that, It always returns the same error ErrorSyntax: invalid syntax. In fact, I tried many combinations and they do not work. The command works only if I put it as it is `python python/classify.py --print_results examples/images/cat.jpg foo` . Even when I tried to enter on python and execute the rest of the command  `python/classify.py --print_results examples/images/cat.jpg foo` it does not works.

Comment: Hmm. There might have been a typo in there. I fixed that and also put in an explicit call to the os.system() function. Take all of the code and replace it, since there is a difference in the imports as well. Finally, try it with a single file first, again, e.g., `f = "cat.jpg"`

Comment: Oh Shawn That`s works. Thank you very much for your great help. You saved my day god bless you. But Can you please explain too me what happen? and Is there any way strore this results like in matlab in a .mat file or text file?

Comment: Yes, there, is, but that should sit under a different question to keep them at the right grain. Ask another. :)