# classify.py is not taking argument --print_results

Tags: python, caffe

I want to run the test on image and detect the image and return the result, but I am facing the following issue:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-6-58:~/caffe$ python python/classify.py  --print_results examples/images/cat.jpg fo
usage: classify.py [-h] [--model_def MODEL_DEF]
                   [--pretrained_model PRETRAINED_MODEL] [--gpu]
                   [--center_only] [--images_dim IMAGES_DIM]
                   [--mean_file MEAN_FILE] [--input_scale INPUT_SCALE]
                   [--raw_scale RAW_SCALE] [--channel_swap CHANNEL_SWAP]
                   [--ext EXT]
                   input_file output_file
classify.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --print_results
ubuntu@ip-172-31-6-58:~/caffe$
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the `classify.py` script, there is no `--print_results` option: https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/python/classify.py

Also, you are not passing the required arguments, which are the `input_file` and the `output_file`. Maybe what you are looking for is the `output_file` that will write the predictions to a file.

Comment: many sites  Eg: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32171454/caffe-how-to-run-classify-py-for-a-set-of-images have specified the input --print_results. 
May be its a python specific thing but why it is not working for me

Comment: Maybe this tutorial is wrong. Searching around I saw also the same issue ( https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/4150 ). Maybe the tutorial override the script or add another example. But this option does not exist

Comment: Is there any other tutorial where i can get the right answer ?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any other tutorial where i can get the right answer ?

Ye, this argument was in another tutorials. You can add this argument to classify.py from here:
https://github.com/jetpacapp/caffe/blob/master/python/classify.py#L93

```
parser.add_argument(
    "--print_results",
    action='store_true',
    help="Write output text to stdout rather than serializing to a file."
)
```

And you need add handler to view results from here:
https://github.com/jetpacapp/caffe/blob/master/python/classify.py#L142

```
if args.print_results:
    with open(args.labels_file) as f:
      labels_df = pd.DataFrame([
           {
               'synset_id': l.strip().split(' ')[0],
               'name': ' '.join(l.strip().split(' ')[1:]).split(',')[0]
           }
           for l in f.readlines()
        ])
    labels = labels_df.sort('synset_id')['name'].values

    indices = (-scores).argsort()[:5]
    predictions = labels[indices]

    meta = [
               (p, '%.5f' % scores[i])
               for i, p in zip(indices, predictions)
           ]

    print meta
```

this code output data results with tags

P.S. I copied the code parts for best view

Comment: I tried this solution, but It cannot find `args.labels_file` anywhere in `classify.py`